# How do eliminate the extra blank pages when using the poetrytex package and adding image to title page?

Tags: titles, verse, poetry

I'm trying to eliminate the extra blank pages: (1) a blank page 2 that appears after the title page, and (2) a blank page page 4 after the poems list. I'm new to LaTeX and can't figure out why these extra blank pages are appearing in my document.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{poetrytex}

\renewcommand*{\pttitle}{My Title}
\renewcommand*{\ptsubtitle}{My Subtitle}
\renewcommand*{\ptauthor}{Author Name}
\renewcommand*{\ptdate}{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\renewcommand*{\topname}{My Poems}
\maketop

\mainmatter

\begin{poem}{Break, break, break}{Tennyson}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{But the tender grace of a day that is dead}

\begin{altverse}
% Incipits are used in the ToP if no title is given.
\incipit{Break, break, break},\\*
On thy cold gray stones, O Sea!\\*
And I would that my tongue could utter\\*
The thoughts that arise in me.
\end{altverse}

\begin{altverse}
O, well for the fisherman's boy,\\*
That he shouts with his sister at play!\\*
O, well for the sailor lad,\\*
That he sings in his boat on the bay!
\end{altverse}

\begin{altverse}
And the stately ships go on\\*
To their haven under the hill;\\*
But O for the touch of a vanish'd hand,\\*
And the sound of a voice that is still!
\end{altverse}

\begin{altverse}
Break, break, break\\*
At the foot of thy crags, O Sea!\\*
But the tender grace of a day that is dead\\*
Will never come back to me.
\end{altverse}

\end{poem}

\end{document}
```

Also, I would like to place an image in my title page. What is the simplest way to go about doing that. Something like this:

Title

Subtitle

*** Image ***

Author Name

Date

Comment: From a typographical point of view, it seems normal  that for books, chapters begin on an odd page. Now, you can try to add the document class option `[openany]`.

Comment: The `book` class starts new chapters on odd pages.  Use a different class, or use the `[openany]` option to the `book` class:  `\documentclass[openany]{book}`.

Comment: If you intend to hard-publish, each new poem starting on the right-hand page (recto) is correct, like a new chapter. Starting something on the back of a leaf (the verso, left-hand side) will be unusual (perhaps you might start a trend, if you do :) ). Whatever choice you make, make it a deliberate choice. PDF readers like to give users one-page view because two-page layout needs big screens to read. So it depends on your audience.

Comment: To include an image on the title page, add `\usepackage{graphicx}` to your premable, and add code to the subtitle or author items: `\renewcommand*{\ptauthor}{Author Name\\ \includegraphics{example-image}`. The `\\ ` is newline command.